# How to transfer large xml file and zip file via rest api?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I have an application which uploads a large file in the XML format and sometimes a zip file. Now I want to have that file transferred to other application via REST API. I am thinking to pass the binary data in to json response.

I have the following questions for my approach.

1. Is sending binary in json the best approach/practice to do it?
2. Will this be PUT scenario as receiver application doesn't know about new uploaded file?

Comment: for the love of god, why would you want to return the binary data in a json response? JSON != REST. Just put a url to the resource in the response and let them GET it.

Comment: That's not what I want to provide. I have been doing with URL in my other projects.

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to build the REST APIs which receive(POST) and send(GET) large XML files. Just looking to have the beast way doing it.

Comment: If you put the binary in json, you have to encode it (making it bigger) and you clients will need to write bespoke code to get the binary from the response and decode it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If that makes it easier for the second service to consume it, I see no problem with it. You can send it on any format you want, as long as it's accepted and you're setting the Content-Type and Accept headers properly.
2. You use a PUT only when you're sending a complete replacement of the resource at the target URI. If you know the final URI for that and if a GET to the same URI right after the PUT will retrieve as response the same body you just submitted, it makes sense to use PUT, otherwise, use a POST.